GTKRadiant doesn't load any assets for Quake 1
I recently decided to see if I could make any maps for Quake 1, seeing how it got a revival recently from Night Dive's remaster.  I downloaded GTKRadiant, and I keep messing with the software's configuration for path to the files, but it never loads any textures or models.
It knows (probably because of its own internal configuration for Quake 1) that there are weapons such as the lightning gun or rocket launcher, but any attempt to place them in the world results in a red box.  It knows that there are enemies such as ogre and shambler, but again, just places a red box.  The only texture is just the no draw or missing texture texture.
I have tried:

Just opening the program and reconfiguring the file path for Quake 1.
Going to the Textures file menu, and attempting to Load Textures.
Opening the configuration (q1.game) file for Quake 1 and typing in the file path.
Downloading a texture WAD file and putting it in several directories that GTKRadiant looks in.

Alas, to no avail.  It is really weird, because I had this problem only yesterday with Quake 3 also (never previously though), and fixed that game configuration in less than ten minutes.
If required, I can provide screenshots of GTKRadiant and the file structure. If there is another editor that would be better for Quake 1, I would also accept that substitute as an answer.
Thanks in advance.
